# Cast (DT_TIMESTAMP) is not consistent from String to DateTime

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl, derived-column

I'm trying to convert an input of DT_WSTR to DT_TIMESTAMP on SSIS Derived column and when I do it the values do not match up, on one ocasion it recognizes the year correctly but on the other it think the day is the year

I tried to do

```
(DT_TIMESTAMP)((DT_WSTR,4)YEAR([Data Hora]) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH([Data Hora]),2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY([Data Hora]),2) + (DT_WSTR,10) Time_Column)
```

with no success

`08-04-19 15:31:27` this is what I input and sometimes it recognizes the 19 as 2019 correctly but other times it thinks the 08 is the year so it puts `19/04/2008`, I want the first one.

I expect to get the date correctly in `dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM:ss`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. In this answer I will try to fix the provided expression. Try using the following expression:

```sql
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)((DT_WSTR,4)YEAR([Data Hora]) + "-" +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH([Data Hora]),2) + "-" + 
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY([Data Hora]),2) + " " + 
(DT_WSTR,10) [Time_Column])
```

Another suggestion is that, in cases where the date format is tricky (2 digit year part), it is better to use a script component to parse the date value since it provides more options using `Date.ParseExact()` function, as example:

```
Row.outDateColumn = DateTime.ParseExact(Row.inStringDate,"dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: @Uruburu https://www.tutorialgateway.org/ssis-script-component-as-transformation/